# Проблема с ssl в dovecot

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, dovecot

Возникает ошибка при подключении к почтовому серверу(postfix+dovecot+mysql):

> imap-login: Error: SSL: Stacked error: error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca: SSL alert number 48

Данные файла /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf

```
ssl = yes
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
ssl_protocols = TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 !SSLv3 !SSLv2
```

Сервер: Ubuntu 16.04
Dovecot: 2.2.22
SSL: StartSSL

dovecot -m imap-login:

```
# 2.2.22 (fe789d2): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.13 (7b14904)
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-042stab134.3 x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04 LTS simfs
# NOTE: Send doveconf -n output instead when asking for help.
auth_debug = yes
auth_ssl_require_client_cert = no
auth_ssl_username_from_cert = no
auth_verbose = yes
base_dir = /var/run/dovecot
config_cache_size = 1 M
debug_log_path =
director_username_hash = %u
disable_plaintext_auth = yes
haproxy_timeout = 3 secs
haproxy_trusted_networks =
imap_capability =
imap_id_log =
imap_id_send = name *
info_log_path =
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
log_timestamp = "%b %d %H:%M:%S "
login_access_sockets =
login_greeting = Dovecot ready.
login_log_format = %$: %s
login_log_format_elements = user=<%u> method=%m rip=%r lip=%l mpid=%e %c session=<%{session}>
login_plugin_dir = /usr/lib/dovecot/modules/login
login_plugins =
login_proxy_max_disconnect_delay = 0
login_source_ips =
login_trusted_networks =
mail_max_userip_connections = 10
shutdown_clients = yes
ssl_client_cert =
ssl_client_key =
ssl_require_crl = yes
state_dir = /var/lib/dovecot
syslog_facility = mail
verbose_proctitle = no
version_ignore = no
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вывод команды:  `doveconf -m imap-login`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cудя по всему это сообщение связано только лишь с тем, что  сертификат `/etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem` самоподписанный.

Т.е. по итогу при первом подключении к серверу почтовым клиентом (например, Mozilla Thunderbird) этот сертификат нужно принять (импортировать в хранилище сертификатов) и всё.

Или, если нужно, чтобы всё было красиво - купить сертификат для этого сервера. Или, если у вас есть корпоративный CA, то выпустить свой. Вобщем, зависит от того, что это у вас за почтовый сервер и насколько вам необходимо "тюнинговать" для него ssl.